# Number matching expressions

Tags: c++, regex, arrays, math

I need to be able to search through an array of numbers for values that match an expression that is entered at run-time.  I was wondering if there is anything similar to regular expression but for numbers specifically?

**To Clarify, my question is "I was wondering if there is anything similar to regular expression but for numbers specifically?"**

@FreeNickname seems to have the right idea, something that could evaluate arithmetic/logical expressions at run-time.

Some simple examples.

I have an array of integers:
100, 145, 675, 0, 250, 43, 19

I want to find any that are between 100-300.
That would be 100, 145, and 250.

I want to find any that are 0, 50, or 100.
 
That would be 100 and 0.

I want to find any that are a multiple of 50.
That would be 0, 100 and 250 (or maybe just 100 and 250, its just an example)

Comment: Why would you want to use regex here? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: In what form will those runtime confitions be entered? If They are entered by a user and they can be expressed as some form of arithmetic/logical expression, then, may be, you should look for some expression parsers/evaluators? And then call it to check every number.
P.S. Seems that everyone pays too much attention to your test examples and skips the fact that expressions have to be entered at runtime.

Comment: @jrd1 I don't want to use regex here, I wondered if there is something like regex, and I haven't yet tried anything, I would like to see what options there are available.

Comment: @FreeNickname The expression will be entered by the user, and an arithmetic/logical expression sounds like exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't anything similar to regular expression but for numbers specifically. As noted by the other responses, you would need to devise something on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need something regex-y? The code sounds simple -

```
while(true){
    cout << "enter the min: ";
    cin >> min;
    cout << "enter the max: ";
    cin >> max;

    for(int i=0;i<ARR_SIZE;i++){
        if(arr[i]>mind && arr[i]<max) cout << arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This code won't help in the second case (where numbers should be specifically 0, 50, 100.

Comment: Nor the 3rd case, and those were only examples, I'm really wondering if there's something more uhm, robust? and regex-y

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can be used to find numbers with special properties in text, but this may not be the best solution.

- Between 100-300: `([12]\d\d)|(300)`
- 0, 50, or 100: `0|(50)|(100)`
- Multiple of 50: `\d*[05]0`

These can (and should) be refined by applying [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) structures (for example, `50` would match not only on `50` but on `250` too, but `(?<=^| )50(?=$|,)` will not), but I think the above examples demonstrate the point. If you can convert your string to an array of numbers, then it's faster to treat the numbers as numbers, as @Dgrin91 suggested.

---

Anyway, the classic example of a "number analyzer regex" is the one used to validate IP addresses:

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

Here you have four integers separated by dots, and every integer must be between 0 and 255.

Answer (score 0):

*"I need to be able to search through an array of numbers for values that match an expression that is entered at runtime"*

What you actually need is:

- read the input into the array of numbers, ideally `std::vector<int>` if vector is an option (allowed)
- parse the *"expression entered at runtime"* using the custom well-defined rules and
- iterate over your array, evaluating a specific condition (range, specific value, etc.)

  You could handle specific cases explicitly (checking for specific string), one of possible approaches:

  ```
  int a[] = {100, 145, 675, 0, 250, 43, 19};
  size_t len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

  std::string expr;
  std::cin >> expr;

  if (expr == "%50") {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
          if (a[i] % 50 == 0)
              ...
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

C++11 has something nice:

```
int min = 100;
int max = 300;
std::vector<int> numbers = {100, 145, 675, 0, 250, 43, 19};
std::vector<int> result(numbers.size());
auto it = std::copy_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), result.begin(),
    [&](int i){return i >= min && i <= max;} );
result.resize(std::distance(result.begin(), it));
```

Use the lambda-function at the end to select which elements you want to remove, for multiples of 50 that would be `return a % 50 == 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> myvector {100, 145, 675, 0, 250, 43, 19};

std::size_t min =100, max=300;

std::cout<<"In Range "<<"[ "<<min<<", "<<max<<" ]"<<std::endl;

std::copy_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
      std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "), 
         [=](const int& x)
         {
           return (x>=min) && (x<=max );
         }
         );

std::cout<<"\nAre [0,50,100]"<<std::endl;
std::size_t a=0,b=50,c=100;
std::copy_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(),
     std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "), 
         [=](const int& x)
         {
           return (x==a) || (x == b ) || (x==c);
         }
         );
std::size_t num=50;        
std::cout<<"\nAre multiple of"<<num<<std::endl;
std::copy_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
     std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "), 
         [=](const int& x)
         {
           return (x%num==0);
         }
         );
```

See [**Was this so difficulty ?**](http://ideone.com/hG0UA8)

Comment: The 3 examples are not difficult.  They are also not my question, simply examples, sorry I will clarify this.